# ansible package module fails because of gpg check (compatibility with other manager modules required)

Tags: ansible

I think something changed somewhere ( not sure if at clients servers because they are newer releases) but suddenly my tasks using the package module are failing because of gpg signature check at Oracle linux and Rhel servers .

I know its an issue from ansible because I see with verbose the gpg check being forced from the ansible play .

We use generic playbooks with the package module (which in time is calling to zypper yum apt etc for each distribution specific package manager) , I know at the yum module we can use
disable_gpg_check: yes

But if I use that option with the package module, it works when running on rhel servers, but fails when running against debian / sles or whatever not using yum module because only yum module has that option, and the other package modules do not .

I would love to find a solution in order to avoid gpg check with yum and still use the generic package module .

The manual command yum install at the server works flawless . Also when I run anisble with verbose (-vvv...) I see the gpgcheck yes being pushed

Comment: `I know its an issue from ansible because I see with verbose the gpg check being forced from the ansible play` <= You would know it's problem with ansible if you had run the same task manually on the target server and it would work as expected and would still fail in ansible. What happens when your run `yum` manually on that server? And unless for a quick workaround in case of a real emergency, you do not want to disable gpg check in yum except if you really don't care about your server security.

Comment: Regarding "_a solution in order to avoid gpg check with yum_" this is something which seems not to be recommended since it is weakening your systems and infrastructure and should be avoided in any case. For a test to narrow down the cause it might be a feasible troubleshooting step.

Comment: Furthermore, you haven't provided any information about your systems, used software versions, configuration files, playbook, output, etc. Can you add the missing information?

Comment: Yes, Ive also ran the yum install on the server and it works ok since it has at the /etc/yum.conf the gpg check disabled and also on the repos

Comment: Systems involved :
Rhel 6.x 7.x 8.x
Oracle Linux 6.x 7.x 8.x
SLES 12.X 15.X
Ubuntu 18.x and 20.x

Tomorrow I will paste the plays output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real solution was adding at playbook time a module defaults for package, with the default(omit) in order to avoid failures when the module package called zypper or apt .

We did that at our "masterplaybooks" that load all the roles :

```
  vars:
    value_for_gpg: "yes"
  module_defaults:    
    package:
      disable_gpg_check: "{{ value_for_gpg | default(omit) }}"
```

Modifying every package task as stated by Zeitounator is not a feasible option since we have more than 100 tasks using the package module into our repositories, but may be an option for others .

What I think is it would be nice that ansible allows direct modification of module defaults directly from group_vars or host_vars

Answer (score 1):

**The real solution to your problem is reactivating gpg checks on the given targets and fix the configuration so it succeeds because it should not be disabled.**

That being said, a possible workaround here:

- Create a group in your inventory (either static or dynamic based on the os name for example) containing all the relevant targets where you want to disable gpg check for yum through the `package` module. I'll call this group `bad_hosts` below
- Add a variable for that group only, for example in `group_vars/bad_hosts.yml`

  ```yaml
  disable_yum_gpg_check: true
  ```
- Modify your task (it took for granted your word saying you can use the option in the `package` task):

  ```yaml
  - name: install package
    package:
      name: some_software
      state: present
      disable_gpg_check: "{{ disable_yum_gpg_check | d(omit) }}"
  ```

Comment: Totally agree, since Im using package module, modifications to yum module are not working . I was able to get it working at play level using :

  module_defaults:
    package:
      disable_gpg_check: yes

Im not sure how to modify the module defaults at group_vars level, I tried to set it into the yaml but its not working, I was only able to get it working at play level , also setting disable_package_gpg_check: true at the group_vars is not working